# Using SUMIF with ExecuteExcel4Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to deal with some closed workbooks and tried to use `ExecuteExcel4Macro` approach and here's some hints
This is the normal formula

```
=SUMIF('[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,C3,'[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C:$C)
```

I used `s` string to store the address of column B and `t` to store the address of column t of the closed workbook

```
s = "'" & myDir & "[" & fn & "]" & "Sheet1" & "'!" & Columns(2).Address(True, True, -4150)
```

the same with the variable t but to change Columns(2) to Columns(3)
And in the immediate window I got something like that
`'C:\Users\Any\Desktop\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!C2`

Then I tried to use

```
Debug.Print ExecuteExcel4Macro("SUMIF(" & s & "," & Range("C3").Address(True, True, -4150) & "," & t & ")")
```

But I encountered an error `Method ExecuteExcel4Macro of object _Global failed`
Any ideas?

Another point how to get the worksheet name without the need to know the name by referring for example: `Worksheets(1).Name` in the variable `s`?

- I noticed that the formula is working when the workbook is open but it throws an error `#VALUE` when the workbook is closed.

Comment: Forget `ExecuteExcel4Macro` for a moment. Can you post the exact Excel formula of sumif (without variables)?

Comment: Please, edit your question and try posting a reproductible example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have updated the question and put the SUMIF formula.

Comment: The variable `myDir ` is the path of the excel file and I have used it in the code. And this is the result of s variable in the immediate window `'C:\Users\Any\Desktop\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!C2`

Comment: You cannot use `ExecuteExcel4Macro` with multiple cells. You can access only one cell at a time from a closed workbook using `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. Even if you could, `SUMIF` will not work for a closed workbook. In lieu of `SUMIF` you can use `SUMPRODUCT` but then `SUMPRODUCT` will only work if you put the formula in a worksheet. In VBA, `Evaluate(SUMPRODUCT())` will give an error from a closed workbook.

Comment: Thank you very much. So there is no way to do that!? What about using `Evaluate(SUMPRODUCT())` ? What's the alternative in that case?